# Import file to install eclipse core plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I am setting up my new eclipse IDE where i will be largely working on RCP, Maven & Web projects. I will be using Mars.

I would like to know if there exists a way that I import a "file" that would contain installation path and in one go install all my plugins that I need for running above projects.?

Instead of manually doing this :
Help > Install > New Software > ...

Answer (score 0):

Oomph feature can help you assemble your IDE, you should check it out.

See this article: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/may/article3.php